# Origin of "soul stones" as prison for souls

Tags: the-elder-scrolls, souls, diablo

One central group of artifacts of *Diablo* is the soul stones, in which the Grand Evils' souls are imprisoned to keep them from reincarnating in Hell.

In the Elder Scrolls universe (the earliest I know is *Morrowind*), there are also soul gems which trap souls, but they are much more common, being used to enchant items and recharge enchanted items.

Common to these two is the theme of a stone that is used to trap a soul without the victims consent. In that they are different to, for example, a Lich's phylactery in D&D.

Do these two share a common origin? Did *Diablo* influence TES here? What is the origin of "stone/crystal used to trap a soul"?

Comment: Soul stones were present in the Elder Scrolls well before Morrowind. Probably back to the original but my mind is fuzzy on details of that game now.

Comment: Daggerfall certainly had them.

Comment: I doubt it's the earliest, but surprised you mention the D&D lich phylactery and not this: https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/trapTheSoul.htm

Comment: I assume its a variation on the old trope of trapping souls in general. TvTropes has a list, though it isn't restricted to just stones: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SoulJar

Comment: The Sealed X In A Can tropes might also be good lists to look into

Comment: The most famous early appearances of soul jars are in the Russian folktales about Koschei the Immortal, a recurring villain whose life force was contained in an egg (or a needle inside the egg).  However, the story pattern is more general; it appears as story type AT 302 ("the giant with no heart") in the  Aarne–Thompson categorization of folktale plots.

Comment: The eldar from Warhammer 40,000 have soul gems and I think that predates TES.

Comment: Merlin's crystal cave (sometimes it's a tree, sometimes both) might also be a source

Comment: @tardigrade It's because I have not actually played much D&D.

Comment: In Jim Starlin's *Warlock* comics from the 1970s, he had a Soul Stone in is forehead which could suck out the souls of living beings, and it was at one point revealed that the souls lived on inside the crystal. Jim's inspiration was probably the soul-suckung sword Stormbringer from his Elric books - which in turn was inspired by the sword Tyrfing in Poul Anderson's 1954 novel *The Broken Swiord*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"soul gems" and imprisoning beings inside them comes from the adventures of Adam Warlock, which Jim Starlin wrote and drew for Marvel Comics. Starlin's comics specifically use the term "soul gem".

https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Adam_Warlock_%28Earth-616%29

Adam gets rid of his arch-nemesis, named Magus (alias Adam's future self), by trapping the latter in a soul gem which the former wears on his forehead.

Comment: Since the answers to this question are likely going to end up competing for the title of "earliest," could you give a date for the comic issues in which the "soul gem" is featured?

Comment: @jwodder: the Magus storyline concluded in mid-1975.

Comment: Good answer, as the question hasn't gotten any attention in several months, I will accept it. Especially since it nicely fits the Diablo "soul gem on forehead" image.